# When I push something it uses Github account

Tags: git, github

I'm on Windows and I'm trying to use my ssh key for some remote git (it's not Github).

I've removed everything in `C:\Users\USER\.ssh` and put correct keys (`id_rsa`, `id_rsa.pub`), nothing is related to Github.

But when I clone some project from that remote git and push something it displays my commits with Github user. I don't get it?

Why does it happen? How to remove Github related account from the system and use my correct ssh?

Comment: The commits are already stored with that info before you push them. You probably configured git with that username/email initially. You can [re-configure that either globally or per-repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37805621/change-email-address-in-git).

Comment: @JoachimSauer thanks so much, `git config user.email "your_email@abc.com"` did the trick, I though that current `id_rsa` file in ssh folder solves everything, but it seems there are much more relations between different things (no just that file key) that I didn't know