# Git Config user email shows testw3school

Tags: git, github

[Screenshot of github](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qWw26.png)

Whenever i initialize git to a folder, and checks the git config user.mail, it shows this
test@w3schools.com , why?

I've to change it manually to my own email, and when i initilize git to another directory it again says w3school email, and when i forget to change it and commit changes to git and pushes it to my private github repo, it shows testw3school commited changes :-(

i was expecting my details but it shows details of w3school, i tried changing it but it again shows that after a while.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Change email address in Git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37805621/change-email-address-in-git) (Pay attention to the global example.)