GitHub Not showing my name when comitting
Basically, I commit but the commit doesn't show my account, it only shows "user " instead of showing my account name with the pfp beside it. It looks like this in the picture.
For your info, I'm new to github and doing this on IntelliJ.

I tried to log in and out from github using IntelliJ. But it showed "Invalid authentication data. Re-Login". I go to Version Control but then see that I am logged in. Could the problem result due to the "Invalid Authentication data" message?

The user name and e-mail on a commit depends on your local git configuration on your machine. You probably just need to run git config --global user.name "My Name" and git config --global user.email "me@mail.ext" with the same e-mail as your GitHub account.

The question is somewhat different, but the answers at https://stackoverflow.com/q/37805621/3216427 apply.
